# Networkx node labels are in wrong order

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have a written a code in Python that draws graphs. The input looks like this:

1. Number of vertices.
2. 1st coordinate of a vertex.
3. 2nd coordinate of the same vertex vertex.
4. Repeat (2) and (3) if there are multiple vertices. Each number must be on a newline.

The graph is drawn correctly, but the labels on each node are wrong.

**Example Input:**

```
10
1
3
3
4
1
2
4
2
3
2
2
6
2
5
6
7
5
8
7
8
4
```

Please enter the input on a newline for each number!!!

**Example output:**

[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh1KX.png)

**My output(wrong one):**

[wrong output(the current one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbBF3.png)

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#f=open("output.txt","r+")
G=nx.Graph()

#ed=input("How many edges?")
ver=int(input("How many vertices?"))


for z in range(0, ver):
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    G.add_edge(x,y)

labelmap = dict(zip(G.nodes(), ["1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8"]))
nx.draw(G, labels=labelmap, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
#, labels=labelmap, with_labels=True
```

Comment: Can you please better explain the format of the input data? Doesn't seem clear to me

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding here but `G.add_edge(x,y)` doesn't draw an edge to the point `x,y` it draws a line connecting node `x` with node `y`. Is this what you want?

Comment: You mean labels of nodes?

Comment: Use `nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)` without `labelmap`. Labels are assigned automatically

Comment: Seems to be producing the correct output for me. Also you have one 21 entries instead of 20 entries after the number of vertices. Recheck that you are providing the inputs correctly. Here's the output for me if I don't enter the last "4" that is there in your entries: https://imgur.com/GWTSiaH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes are added automatically by `networkx` the first time they are referenced. If you draw an edge from C->B then F->A the nodes will be created in that order (C, B, F, A). However your `labelmap` is assuming they are in numerical order.

The node labels will be printed correctly on the nodes if you just use:

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Or you can track the nodes as you add them to store the order, e.g.

```
nodes = []
for z in range(0, ver):
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    G.add_edge(x,y)

    if x not in nodes:
        nodes.append(x)
    if y not in nodes:
        nodes.append(y)

labelmap = dict(zip(nodes, nodes))
```

Using this approach you could also format/change the label if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments labels in `networkx` are assigned automatically:

```
import networkx as nx
from string import ascii_uppercase

G = nx.Graph()

edges = list(zip(ascii_uppercase, ascii_uppercase[1:]))
print(edges)

for i, j in edges:
    G.add_edge(i, j)

# jupyter notebook
%matplotlib inline
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

#### Output:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'F'), ('F', 'G'), ('G', 'H'), ('H', 'I'), ('I', 'J'), ('J', 'K'), ('K', 'L'), ('L', 'M'), ('M', 'N'), ('N', 'O'), ('O', 'P'), ('P', 'Q'), ('Q', 'R'), ('R', 'S'), ('S', 'T'), ('T', 'U'), ('U', 'V'), ('V', 'W'), ('W', 'X'), ('X', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Z')]
```

[image: Graph]

By default nodes/vertices in `networkx` have integers as labels:

```
G = nx.path_graph(15)
print(G.edges())

%matplotlib inline
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

#### Output:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14)]
```

[image: Graph]